# Login authentication always failed

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm doing PHP Laravel authentication. Registration and email activation seem works well. But when comes to login, it always return false. I have no idea about this. My email, password and active columns seems correct in my database.

**User Modal**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
protected $fillable = array('email', 'username', 'password', 'password_temp', 'code', 'active');

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

**Login.php**

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('login-post')}}" method="post"> 
                    <!--/ sign in title-->

                    <!--text field-->
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border" {{ (Input::old('email') ? ' value="'.Input::old('email') . '"' : '') }}> 
                        @if($errors->has('email'))
                            {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                        @endif
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border" {{ (Input::old('password') ? ' value="'.Input::old('password') . '"' : '') }}> 
                        @if($errors->has('password'))
                            {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                        @endif
                    </div> 
                    <!--/ text field-->

                    <div class="text-center m-t m-b">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
                        <label for="remember">
                            Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning lt b-white b-2x btn-block btn-rounded"></input>
                    {{ Form::token() }}
                </form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function postSignIn() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        )
    );  

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('login')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    }else {

        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

        //Attempt user sign-in
        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1
        ), $remember);

        if ($auth) {
            //Redirect to the intended page
            return Redirect::intended('home');
        }else {
            return Redirect::route('login')
                    ->with('global','Email/Password is wrong or account is not activated.'.Hash::make(Input::get('password')));
        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('global','There was a problem signing you in.');
}
```

**Problem**
It returns incorrect password always.

**Solution**
Password length must be at least 60 in database for Laravel.

Comment: did you Hash::make() when you store the password into your database?

Comment: @goldlife yes, I have hash::make my pas Thsword before I stored into database.

Comment: do you have 
`'driver' => 'eloquent', 'model' => 'User', 'table' => 'users', `
in your config/auth.php ?

Comment: @goldlife By default, yes.

Comment: is your password field in your database at least 60 characters long? Laravel creates a 60 char hash.

Comment: @goldlife Problem solved. Thanks you. Yeah. My password char was 50 previously.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two reasons (one or maybe two in the same time could couse this)

**ONE** : when you store your passwords you didn't hash them `Hash::make()`

**TWO** : you modified your `config/app.php` `[key]` value after setting your pass

Comment: ONE : I did hashmake on my password before register, my database table password column already shows some sorts of encryption.

TWO: I didn't touch a single line of code in config/app.php before.

Comment: How you seed your pass ?

Comment: You have to change the `key => 'YourKey'` property in you `config/app.php`

Comment: @violator667 Nope, didn't changed.

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta My key ? Simply set a random key ?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner try to run this commands, in order:

- `php artisan key:generate`
- `php artisan clear-compiled`
- `php artisan dump-autoload`

The second and the third are not mandatory, just to be sure :D